# What are way to represent Zebra(Einstein) Puzzle mathematical or formal form

Tags: logic, puzzle

I look how to implement the algorithm (program) for solving so called Zebra(Einstein) Puzzle.
For that, i look for some formal or mathematical representation of conditions in this puzzle.
Can you suggest possible ways to represent it, while this representation should makes easier to solve that?
Of course, do not suggest the trivial forms, like list of all possible variants, this is not efficient if there are too many variants.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have done much work on your problem yourself. There are links on the Wikipedia page for the puzzle that lead to approaches to modelling the terms in this puzzle. Have you tried any of those approaches? What were your experiences?